# Unexpected parameter: id

Tags: twitter, extract, tweepy

While writing the Python code for Twitter extraction in Jupyter notebook I am getting the error as `Unexpected parameter: id`. Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Looks like you need to remove an `id=..` parameter from some function, but we need more info. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the relevant code and/or full traceback for anyone to know what exactly is going on, but that's likely just a warning that you're passing an `id` parameter to an `API` method that doesn't expect it.

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) changed many `API` methods to no longer accept `id` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use screen_name instead of id parameter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).